# How do I create an AWS server that could recieve data continously from an IOS(swift) app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to code an IOS application and already have an ec2 server designated for the app. I want to know how the app could send image data to the server. The ec2 server would receive incoming image data continuously from all the users that use the app. The server would then process the data. It would be similar to what applications such as Instagram do but, of course not at such a large scale.

I am a beginner at client-server communication and want to know how to implement this into my app. I also do not use stack overflow too frequently, so please tell me if I am doing something wrong if you need more information.

To be more specific, a user would post an image in the app. I currently have already set up an ec2 server to possibly receive that image. I want all of the images that users post to be delivered, processed, then stored in the ec2 server. Is there some way to handle the actual delivery of data. The question is a little broad because I want to know where to look. Would I have to write a script that is constantly running in the background and receiving data at some port? Is there another service I could use that handles this?

Comment: This question is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, briefly, you'll have issues with running on an EC2 if you have many users sending images at the same time.

Look into setting up `API Gateway <-> Lambda <-> DynamoDB or S3` on AWS. Then your client can `POST` images/data to your gateway with a HTTP request.

Comment: Not to mention that the storage costs of EBS are a lot higher than S3. Basically, it's not cost-effective to store your images on the disk that's attached to the EC2 instance.

Comment: I looked into Lambda and using S3 or redshift instead of an EC2 server. I decided to use Kinesis data firehouse paired with a redshift data warehouse at the end.

Comment: @NikhilChandra - Kinesis and Redshift to store data? Thats not a good fit beside both of those are expensive. If there are other things outside of what you explained that need these features fine. But just to store data, that's really not what they are meant for.

Comment: So would you suggest simply using lambda to handle incoming data, and s3 for storing it instead? I am a bit new to this so I just want to learn as much as possible for setting up the backend of my app.

Comment: I was initially thinking I could use a kinesis stream that would consume data from the client and then send it to a redshift or s3 data warehouse to store the data.

Comment: @NikhilChandra Yes, lambda would read the HTTP data and read/write it from/to S3.

Answer (score 0):

First you must decide if your data is streaming (continuously pushed from server) or stored (pulled from the server as needed). The Instagram example you provided suggest that you have no need for real-time streaming data.

A streaming solution is more complicated and may typically require a technology like web sockets (or AWS `IoT`) to accomplish. A storage solution will be much simpler.

For storing you have the choice between creating and managing server(s) using a platform like `EC2` (you'll need more than one server to scale to many users), or using  managed 'serverless' technology like `Lamba` where you only need provide the code. The tradeoff is for this convenience is usually price.

For image storage, a typical pattern is creating database records that contain an `S3` URL for the underlying image (as well as any metadata). You can create this database record and upload your file using whatever server technology you choose; Lambda may require an `API Gateway` server but remember that the AWS SDK can invoke `Lambda` functions directly.

Comment: I checked out lambda, and tried comparing it to using google cloud functions. I think as more of a beginner although lambda might be better in some aspects, google cloud has been much easier to work with and is easier to set up and deploy.

Comment: @NikhilChandra I agree and highly recommend using Google Cloud instead for a beginner